# Implement Location Tracking in Android

Tags: android

I want to track the user location at **every 1 minute** and store user location in database.
If the user location does not change for 30 min then i have to give the notification to user and if user does not close app at particular time.
e.g: 8.00 pm then also i have to give notification to user

The tracking should be in separate thread so that app can perform other task while location tracking is in progress.

I am totally stuck in this that how can i make separate thread for **three things**:

1. for location tracking
2. for 30 min reminder notification
3. for 8.00 pm reminder

if the notification is shown to user and if the location changes then notification should be removed and tracking should be done normally

Comment: please help me. plz guide me how can i perform threading for separate location update and for notification

Comment: You must use a thread with a service in your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Service for this, and in service you can implement the location listener with with one minute interval, and for battery optimization you should you [Google Location API](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html). And you also use the Activity recognition for finding out the user movement.

Comment: may u provide some example to initiate it

Answer (score 1):

I see no need to use threading for this.  The Android documentation on the [location strategy page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) defines how to get updates on the location, and the [Countdown timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) can be used to do your timing.

Comment: except you shouldn't be running all this different logic on the main thread from a "background" `Service` - that will impact on your foreground UI of all other apps. -- that is why you would want to spawn other threads in the `Service`

Comment: @Richard  Both the location APIs and the countdown timer APIs are callbacks and therefore non-blocking, therefore non-blocking.

Comment: Of course yes! +1 cos you've pointed out something so obvious, yet have also shown me a poor design bug in my tracker (actually I'm not multithreading it, but am calling startService too often). Sometimes it takes a fresh perspective to see something clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Your battery life will suck if you check the location every minute.

Anyway, all of these tasks can be completed by using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). You'll set up a time for the next event and when it happens your code will run, even if your Activity is in the background. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "close the app at 8 pm", the app doesn't need to be visible for these things to happen.

Comment: "close the app" means i have to stop the tracking

Comment: You'd be better off adding a button to your app that disables (and enables!) the tracking. Or do you expect the user to not be able to use his device?

Comment: i added button already but if the user forget to click the close button then i have to give the notification

Comment: Sure, just don't make the users keep the activity open :)